# strong password regex

Tags: regex

OK so I have a mental block when it comes to regex - but I was told to come up with a regex expression that met these conditions:

- must be at least 8 characters (easy!)
- must have characters from at least 3 of the 4 different character types - upper case, lower case, digits, symbols (ok)
- must have at least 5 different characters
- must not have a long sequence of the same character type (eg. asdnme would be considered bad as its a long sequence of lower case)

```
(?=^.{8,255}$)((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s]))
```

This regex expression satisfies 1 and 2.  But I am struggling to find examples for 3 and 4.

If any regex enthusiasts could help me - it would be appreciated. :)

Note: I would prefer not to use Regex - this is me asking anyone if it's possible to check for the 3rd and 4th condition using regex?  And please don't downvote me for the belief that regex is the only solution.  I don't believe it is - our achitect decided the least effort would be involved in using regex to solve this issue.

Personally I think this level of password security is going to make the system unusable!!! But maybe I don't care enough about password security :)

Note: We're trying to make use of the Microsoft ASPNET Membership - regex expression.  Which is why I thought it needed to be a single expression.  I get that it's horrible to try to read/understand.

If anyone can provide individual regex expressions for 
- must have at least 5 different characters
- must not have a long sequence of the same character type (eg. asdnme would be considered bad as its a long sequence of lower case) - assume 5 sequence is too long..

Or c# code /javascript ? Although this is specific to one particular client - we don't want it blanked applied to all clients.  Which is probably why the architect wanted a nice regex expression that you could just slot in at deployment time. :(

Found someone else's example that works in .NET

^(?!.*(.)\1{2})((?[A-Z])|(?[a-z])|(?\d)|(?[^A-Za-z\d])){8,}(?(Upper)(?(Lower)(?(Numeric)|(?(NonAlphaNumeric)|(?!)))|(?(Numeric)(?(NonAlphaNumeric)|(?!))|(?!)))|(?(Lower)(?(Numeric)(?(NonAlphaNumeric)|(?!))|(?!))|(?!)))$

Unfortunately it meets these conditions:

- Must have a minimum length of 8 characters
- Must contain characters from three of the four following types:
- English upper-case characters (A - Z)
- English lower-case characters (a - z)
- Numerical digits (0 - 9)
- Non-alphanumeric characters
- No character can be repeated 3 or more times in a row, e.g.
  BB (letter B twice) is OK, but BBB (letter B 3 times) is NOT OK.

But it doesn't detect that at least 5 different characters are used :(

Nevermind - the answer below seems to work.  Only thing is that it appears to allow 4 different characters rather than requiring 5?

I have tweaked it to be:
^(?=.{8,})(?:(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s]))(?=(.)(?>.*?(?!\1})(.))(?>.*?(?!\1}|\2)(.))(?>.*?(?!\1|\2|\3)(.))(?>.*?(?!\1|\2|\3|\4)(.))(?>.*?(?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5).))(?!.*?\d{4})(?!.*?[a-z]{4})(?!.*?[A-Z]{4})(?!.*?[^A-Za-z0-9\s]{4})

Here's hoping we never have to touch it again ;)  With more time if this crops up again I'll push the code option I think :)

**Edit: Discovered that the string isn't quite right.  It's not passing "!tt23yyy" without having to add another digit or special character.  So have canned the regex idea and am going with the code option.  It's just too hard to debug regex issues if you don't comprehend regex :) (understandably so)**

Comment: You want to cram too much into a single regex... It's already unreadable, if you manage to get everything in, then it will be impenetrable for anyone. Is there a specific requirement that you *must* use only *one* regex?

Comment: Does it have to be in one pass? You can't really provide much feedback to a user on why it failed if your doing it in one go.

Comment: Why use regex for this? Especially a single one? You wouldn't be able to tell the user which one of your weird requirements the user broke?

Comment: -1 for believing a single regex is the only solution to all problems.  Epic FAIL.

Comment: @Jen, "must have characters from at least of the different character types", at least what? At least one? At least two?

Comment: I don't even understand what the 4th requirement means, what is "long" exactly?

Comment: Please don't down vote me - our architect said it had to be done in regex - I personally think regex isn't the way to go - I'm just trying to find out if there is an expression that can be used :(

Comment: @Qtax thanks - fixed my question to include the useful information :)

Comment: @inTide I don't have that information - but if there was a way of doing it so that you could substitute a value - ie. if there was a regex expression for finding say 5 letters used before another character type was present.

Comment: @Jen Sorry for having down voted your question.  Anyway... "WHERE IS THE MANAGER?"  :P  It's time NOT to listen to the architect if he/she doesn't give you a reason why it had to done in a single regex.

Comment: @shinkou thanks.. I just don't want to be labelled as epic fail - if it's not my doing :)

Comment: "our architect said it had to be done in regex" - get a new architect; why does it have to be regex? what is the rational? This is a nice short boolean expression without regex (and faster).

Comment: @Jen It looks like a single regex is NOT a must.  *If you create custom login controls, you must call the ValidateUser method to validate the user’s user name and password.* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx

Comment: If you make it too human unfriendly you will need a regex to look to see if the users don't have a post it note stuck to their monitor with the password on it since it will be the only way to remember it. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a PCRE/Perl regex that would do all that:

```
/
^ # anchor it

# must be at least 8 characters
(?=.{8,})

# must have characters from at least 3 of the 4 different character types
(?: 
  (?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])
| (?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s])(?=.*[a-z])
| (?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])
| (?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s])
)

# at least 5 different chars
(?=
                       (.)
  (?>.*?(?!\1})        (.))
  (?>.*?(?!\1}|\2)     (.)) 
  (?>.*?(?!\1|\2|\3)   (.)) 
  (?>.*?(?!\1|\2|\3|\4) . )
)

# no long sequence of the same character type (if long is 3)
(?!.*?\d{3})
(?!.*?[a-z]{3})
(?!.*?[A-Z]{3})
(?!.*?[^A-Za-z0-9\s]{3})

/xs
```

Not tested so could have missed something. Enjoy. ;-)

If you are really going to be using that (on longer strings), you might want to add some (more) atomic grouping `(?>foo)` (or the like) to prevent exponential backtracking.

Comment: Also could anchor that with a `^` at the beginning, and those `\g{-N}` can be rewritten to corresponding `\N` (if not supported, I used them in case there would be other capturing groups).

Comment: Last part - noticed that these don't seem to be picking up multiple letters (either lower case or upper case) - but the symbols and numbers work. ie. these statements (?!.*?[a-z]{3}) (?!.*?[A-Z]{3})

Comment: @Jen, need to anchor the regex by adding a `^` at the beginning of it. I've updated the regex.

Comment: Doesn't help that this free tool I downloaded has stopped properly validating regex as valid/not valid.. :) Have found an online one so I'll continue to play.  Thanks again!!

Comment: @Jen, you could install Perl and use http://codepad.org/1H9xq6tu (or just use that site). ;-)

Comment: I don't think using Perl as part of our site is an option :)