# Regular expression for login (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, authentication

I need some help with regular expression. I need check login, login can have letters, numbers and underscore. It must have at least one letter and can have a underscore in center.

Now I have this:
`^([a-z0-9_])+$/iu`
But it allow to use all in any order.

Comment: does `in center` mean that you dont want an underscore at the start..and in what order do you want it to be

Comment: Yes, for example: `word_word`, but not `_word` or `word_`

Comment: max one underscore, or also more than one?

Comment: You did not specify the order in which the elements are allowed to appear. Can you make some examples of valid and invalid usernames, too?

Comment: @user1821941 ur question is very incomplete..we cant guess what is in your mind

Comment: possible duplicate of [strong password regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618808/strong-password-regex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one here:

```
^(?<=[a-z])(?<=[0-9])[a-z0-9]+(_[a-z0-9]+|)$/iu
```

So there must be a letter or a number at the beginning at least one time. That can optional come one _ with minimum of one more letters/numbers or nothing instad.

The `(?<=[a-z])` is a *positive look-behind assertion* which means that a letter must be inside.

Comment: Now it don't allow to use only letters

Comment: In this case you need just to add a second *positive look-behind assertion*.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for this

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z\d].*)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z\d]$)(?=[^_]*(_)?[^_]*$)[a-zA-Z\d_]+$
  ---------------  ------------ ---------------- ---------------
        |              |                |              |->this checks that there is 0 to 1 occurance of _
        |              |                |->this checks if it ends with any of [a-zA-Z\d]
        |              |->this checks if there is atleast 1 alphabet
        |->this checks that it starts with [a-zA-Z\d]
```

test it [here](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: It work too, but variant from rekire is better, because it's smaller. But thank you too!

Comment: @user1821941 yes rekire solution is small is sweet but i always use `lookaheads` in multiple matches..this do make `regex` huge but you can debug it later without any confusion